# What is the reason the Kronecker delta function is noted this way in DSP?

Tags: dirac-delta-impulse, notation

I'm trying to make sense of different notations used in DSP. This is sometimes quite hard since notation brackets like in x[n] are used both to denote a single value or a sequence.

In mathematics, the generalized [Iverson bracket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) is:

$$[P]=\begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if P is true}\\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

and [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) is noted either:
$$\delta_{n,m}=\begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } n=m\\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

or:

$$[n=m]=\begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } n=m\\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

In DSP ([example](https://web.uettaxila.edu.pk/CMS/AUT2012/cpDSPbs/labs%5CDSP%20Lab%202.pdf)), $\delta_{n,m}$ is noted $\delta[n-m]$, a mix of the two mathematics forms I find confusing because as $\delta[n-m]$ is legitimate, then is $\delta[n-1-m]$ legitimate too?

My questions to experienced DSP community:

- Why this notation and not the mathematical one which seems more clear?
- Is $\delta[n-1-m]$ legitimate? If so, what is its signification?

Comment: FWIW, I find the mathematical notation much less clear. :-) YMMV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that one symbol (in this case $x[n]$) is used to denote a sequence or a single number is nothing that is specific to DSP. If you have a continuous function $f(t)$, then this symbol is used to denote the function but also to refer to its value at $t$, if $t$ is some fixed number in the domain of $f$.

Since we use the notation $x[n]$ to denote sequences (or some specific value of that sequence), it seems natural to define a *sequence* $\delta[n]$, which is zero everywhere except for $n=0$ where it equals $1$. That's why this sequence is also called the *unit impulse (sequence)*.

Referring to your last question, of course $\delta[n-1-m]$ is legitimate. It is zero everywhere except when $n-1-m=0$.

As a final comment, note that $\delta[n]$ is mathematically totally unrelated to the distribution $\delta(t)$, also called *Dirac impulse*, even though $\delta[n]$ plays a similar role in discrete time as does $\delta(t)$ in continuous time.

Comment: Re. to "*f(t), then this symbol is used to denote the function but also to refer to its value at t, if t is some fixed number*", Is it legitimate to substitute  $n$ in an equation as we do for any mathematical function? E.g for a convolution, $y[n]=x_{1}[n]\ast x_{2}[n]\Longrightarrow y[4]=x_{1}[4]\ast x_{2}[4]$?

Comment: @mins: The problem here is that the notation $x_1[n]*x_2[n]$ doesn't make much sense in the first place. It should be $(x_1*x_2)[n]$. Then $(x_1*x_2)[4]$ does make sense. Same in continuous time: $f(t_0)*g(t_0)$ is meaningless.

Comment: "*The problem here is that the notation x1[n]∗x2[n] doesn't make much sense in the first place*", this notation is commonly seen, e.g. [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87028/56622), so the comment about confusing use of brackets in my question. [You do use](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/33463/56622) the correct notation.

Comment: @mins: Yes, it's quite common, and if just used to denote convolution - without the need to refer to a specific element of the resulting sequence - then it's kind of OK. However, it has obvious shortcomings which become obvious when you refer to a specific element. The result of convolution is a sequence and in general you need to denote as such, i.e., with a *single* independent variable: $(x_1*x_2)[n]$. But again, this is a general problem, regardless whether you refer to discrete time or continuous time.